# Meteor: mongoimport command not found

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongoimport

I'm using meteor and I need to use `mongoimport` to add some JSON-data to the DB. But when I try to start meteor import, I got the error `command not found`. This is surprising for me as mongoimport is part of mongoDB, so I expected this working.

So I guess I have to install MongoDB separately from meteor (using OS X). But what is the correct way to do that?

Of course I can do `brew install mongodb`. Or would it be better to download the mongodb-file manually, extract the archive and take the mongoimport-file?

I'm just worried to install mongodb, although I already have meteor installed and it works. I don't want to get two different mongoDB instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have the mongoimport binary somewhere, just download MongoDB for OSX from their site, extract the archive somewhere, and use the mongoimport file that will be in its bin folder.

You won't get another daemon running unless you run another mongod and you are probably safest to avoid using brew so that it doesn't do something unintended.

Comment: Thanks. And where should I put the mongoimport-file? I copied the file into the meteor-app root but I still get the error `command not found`. I don't understand that.

Comment: I didn't realize that Meteor was calling mongoimport, I thought you were directly running mongoimport from the command line. A guess: Can you try a 'which mongo' to see what mongo is in your path, and try putting it there? I assume it will be something like /usr/local/meteor/mongodb/bin

Comment: Also, can you show what you mean when you say "try to start meteor import"?  You can use mongoimport without involving meteor.

Comment: That's what I tried. I just type `mongoimport` in the shell - so far meteor isn't involved. Then I get the message `command not found`

Comment: Are you running ./mongoimport in your bash shell, in the directory where mongoimport exists? If it is not in your path, make sure to precede with ./